# Is there a ruby library for checking whether a string is a valid word?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to isolate the single words in a pdf file, but when reading the file using the pdf-reader gem the text arrives fractured, like this

```
"A lit"
"tle "
"bit of tex"
"t"
```

So I'm planning to put these together using some heuristics. For this, I need a library which checks if a given string is a valid english word, like

```
"tree".is_english? # => true
"askdjfah".is_english? # => false
```

Does this exist? Ideally, it would also work with german text.

If not, is there some freely available dictionary online? I guess I could write my own tree structure to do the lookup, if i had to.

Comment: To do what you want, a library would have to *incorporate* a dictionary. Given that no-one knows how many words there are in the English language (and it's increasing all the time) it would be difficult to provide complete coverage, without even considering *other languages*. You can certainly download a dictionary and roll your own, but I think you'll find the coverage inadequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [raspell](http://blog.evanweaver.com/files/doc/fauna/raspell/files/README.html), or even manually invoking `aspell`, with any dictionary you like.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the unix tool `look` installed on your system, you can check whether a word is a word easily. Example:

```
strings = %w{ cat dog tree trees treez }

strings.each do |string|
  if system("look #{string} > /dev/null 2>&1") 
    puts "#{string} is a word"
  else
    puts "#{string} is not a word"
  end
end
```

Here's more information on `look`: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch27_18.htm

Since look uses the word dictionary in /usr/dict/words, I think it's possible to install a German word dictionary. Look for the wgerman package in Debian. I'm not sure how to install it on other systems.

Comment: it seems to look for the prefix in dictionary, anyway to look for exact string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any library that do what you want, but there are dictionaries with words. It shouldn't be hard to find them on google. For example [this](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/).